# Dummy SQL query

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am creating an install file for a script I created and will also provide the fields to enter the database details. Anyway, before storing those database details in a config.php file, I'd like to see if they work. What would be the best way to see if the provided details are valid? I thought of running a dummy query and if it's successful then store the details in a file. I don't know what the best query would be? I am using PDO for the whole thing. So, I basically need to check if a database connection succeeded in order to continue.

Could you please tell me your ideas how to verify if everything is alright with the user input? Is my dummy query idea a good way to handle this? If yes, what query should I run? If no, what do you suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: See the manual, Example #2 Handling connection errors: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php ...ah, but I suppose you'll want to check permissions as well, right?

Comment: @WesleyMurch Yes, permissions need to be checked too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check if PHP connects to the database correctly (returned values, mysql errors). Then You can use something like `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%"` to determine the database engine version, so all functions and methods will work as intended. This way You can also inform Your users, that their db version is to old to be used with Your software.

**EDIT**

Also, a query of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host'` is a good idea to check permissions for connected user

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sql server somethig like "select 1" will do the job. I guess many other database engines will support this query too.

Comment: The downside of `SELECT` being inability to test permissions. Creating tables, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to issue a series of queries/commands that test every thing you need individually.

1. Can open connection
2. Database is there/can be created
3. User can see data/can construct data
   etc..

Then as part of the installation you can tell the user if something isn't right and point them directly at the problem for them to solve. You should do this early in the installation so that you don't have to roll back too much.

Think about the installation experience. What would you want when installing a program. Would you like it to just say

```
 "Error. Can't connect", 
 or 
 "Error: Cannot connect to DATABASEX the SERVERY with the USERID_W", 
 or even better 
 "Error: Can connect to the DATABASEX the SERVERY with the USERID_W, but table X is missing, have you completed step ABC first?"
```

Do as much work as you can for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can assume the connection is successful if the connection function returns the expected value without generating any errors/exceptions. Aside from that...

`SHOW TABLES FROM $database;`

Should show that they have at least basic permissions to the database, but won't indicate if they can create tables and insert data.